# Remove \r from list

Tags: python, list

I have a list that looks like this:

```
['\r1/19/2015', '1/25/2015\r']
```

I got this data from the web, and it just started coming with the `\r` today. This causes an error in my script, so I am wondering how to remove the `\r` from the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip). `'\r'` is a carriage return, and `strip` removes leading and trailing whitespace and new line characters.

```
>>> l = ['\r1/19/2015', '1/25/2015\r']
>>> l = [i.strip() for i in l]
>>> l
['1/19/2015', '1/25/2015']
```

Comment: this will only work if the escape sequence is at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: ... which is exactly what I said

Answer (score 4):

You can use `replace` also

```
>>> l = ['\r1/19/2015', '1/25/2015\r']
>>> [i.replace('\r','') for i in l]
['1/19/2015', '1/25/2015']
```

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason the `\r` characters are not just at the beginning and/or end of your strings, the following will work:

```
In [77]: L = ['\r1/19/2015', '1/25/2015\r', '1/23/\r2015']

In [78]: [item.replace("\r", "") for item in L]
Out[78]: ['1/19/2015', '1/25/2015', '1/23/2015']
```